# Missing file from repository this morning. Who do I notify?

Tags: 12.04, repository, aptitude

Aptitude upgrade on 12.04 shows the following:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-libc-dev_3.2.0-84.121_amd64.deb: 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
```

How can i fix this ?

Comment: Packages get regular updates. You need to also update your apt cache before installing something by running `sudo aptitude update`.

Answer (score 0):

After googling `linux-libc-dev_3.2.0-84.121_amd64.deb` on Ubuntu's website it gives a 404 , probably it's been deleted. Try installing it from aptitude or synaptic